# CSS for fixing header

Tags: lightning-aura-components

From Lightning Component guide Expense object example, i thought of fixing header part& form for new record values  and only scrolling for next existing records. i am not strong guy in CSS but tried with couple of setting like position:fixed etc. Nothing is worked in SF1 app.

please help to achieve this.